# RegExp to get any number + `;#`?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, numbers

I have several numbers in a string, such as:

```
8;#
10;#
34;#
etc...
```

I wanted to erase all of these from the string, so was thinking RegExp would be my best option.

What regexp expression do I use that will identify any series of numbers followed by `;#` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this this:

```
\d+;#
```

I don't know AS3 but I think your code should look something like this:

```
var r:RegExp = /\d+;#/;
var s:String = "foo 8;# bar 10;#baz 34;#   bah";
var x:String = s.replace(r, "")
```

Comment: That removes the 1st occurrence, so the output is: foo  bar 10;#baz 34;#   bah // I'll see how I can make it persist. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just found out how to make it persist. RegExp should look like: /\d+;#/g   Tks once again :)